# Sorting a dictionary of pairs based on value

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have the code

```
mydict = {"layer1" : { 0: 0.765}, 'layer2': {0: 0.9876}}
for idx in range(5):
   mydict['layer1'][idx] = idx + 900
   mydict['layer2'][idx] = idx + 800
sorted_x = sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1])
```

it gives the error

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'

when I type

```
sorted_x = sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[2])
```

it gives the error

> IndexError: tuple index out of range

it onley works for index 0 which is a string!

I want the dictionary to be sorted based on the value and give the results like

> [('layer2', {0: 800, 1: 801, 2: 802, 3: 803, 4: 804}), ('layer1', {0: 900, 1: 901, 2: 902, 3: 903, 4: 904})]

what should I do?

Comment: how come your expected outcome is way too different from `mydict`?

Comment: Hint: think about what the argument to the key function is going to be. If you change the function to use `def` instead of lambda, you can print the argument. That should give you some hint as to what the expression to extract the sorting key needs to be.

Comment: @subspring This OP has difficulty defining the key function for their particular case. Is that really covered in that other question and its answers?

Comment: "what should I do?" - You should tell us what exactly "based on the value" means. Python told you with that error that it doesn't know how you want to compare those dictionaries, and neither do we.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple change you can put in your code:

Change

```
sorted_x = sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1])
```

to:

```
sorted_x = sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1][1])
```

Comment: Did you put anything after the colon?

Comment: the question that I described is sorted but it's not exactly what I need. what I want is: if ['layer1][0] = 9 and ['layer2'][0] = 9 and everything else is 0, I want the output of my sort be those two at the beginning of the list. this updated version of the code that you kindly provided doesn't do that. what should I do?